# Invensense IMU3000 with PIC

Tags: pic, i2c, c, imu, mplab

Has anybody experienced using the Invensense IMU3000 gyroscope with some microcontroller?

The hardware comes with a really good library integrating full control of its features. This library is structured in 3 different layers, the bottom one is the one that implements the communication with the chip itself. The vendor provides this layer for using the IMU3000 with an adapter board in WindowsXP. Basically, what I need to do (and what is suggested in the application note) is rewrite this layer to use the whole library with my PIC (I2C communication). After that, I can just use the library (this is what it's said in the application note).

I am trying to build the IMU library in Visual Studio 2005 (the project was originally made this way) for a PIC but I am stuck with the dependencies..

Alternatively, I can compile the .lib with the PIC IDE, but.. is it possible=

Any hint, even with other platforms, would help!

Thank you all!

P.S. Unfortunately I cannot find the DS online.. just after you install the package you find it.

Comment: Regarding `.lib`'s: [Not only is a `.lib` file CPU specific, it is toolchain specific.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3120308/is-a-c-lib-file-platform-specific)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt you'll be able to compile the libraries (meant for Visual Studio from what I can tell) in MPLAB - the targets are insanely different (desktop PC vs PIC microcontroller).  It seems to me that the directions they gave you with the libraries are meant to be followed if you want to use the chip with your desktop PC.  I doubt you'll be able to modify the libraries to allow them to compile and run with the PIC.  Instead, you should examine the code and try to re-implement it on your own for the PIC.  The code can give you an idea of what to do but you won't be saving yourself any time trying to use it directly.

Answer (score 1):

I bought an IMU3000 too, i installed that software that invensense rold me to, and i managed to compile it somehow, and get a libfile out of the whole thing. I am trying to make it work with a pic too...im using pic18f4550..but i dont even know where to start. Are those source codes of some use? or should i forget about it, and try writing my own stuff for this?

Comment: Hey! so we are both using a pic18, that could make things easier.. I believe the idea of compiling as a library makes no sense, as I dunno how such a thing can be done for a PIC. I started by looking at the code (which wasn't fitting my PIC) and commenting stuff which wasn't needed and trying to write equivalent functions for those functions which aren't available on a PIC (such as all the stuff in aio.c/h) and expecially by rewriting the MLSL functions (I'm having some problem with the WriteBurst one). Maybe when u'll have started digging a bit we can compare our result!

Comment: One thing is that what you compiled was compiled for windows, no way that library can be used on a PIC.. I tried to contact Invensense several times about thata bu I got no answer... let me know if you manage to get some info..

Answer (score 0):

Uh? Has MS Visual Studio suddenly sprouted support for PIC cross compilation?
... or are you doing something sneaky to get MSVC to use your crosscompiler?

What kind of PIC are you using?
What cross compiler are you using?

Comment: I just tried to do so in MSVC with no crosscompiler.. but I see this is no good!
I'm using the PIC18F87J11.
Right now I gave up with MSVC and imported all the .h and .c files into MPLAB and trying to build the whole thing together (the vendor suggested to first build the library and then the application, loading the library in it) but I am experiencing a number of errors I'm trying to correct one by one.. is this somehow the right thing to do?

I've some experience with PICs but I never had to implement some external library and to adapt it so any hint is super welcome!

Comment: If it's of any help, I'm using the C18 compiler from Microchip